# Back button seems disabled iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In iOs I navigate (pushed) with a navigation controller, and in the viewDidLoad launch a request. This request take might take a long time, and I'd like the users will be able to go back if they won't want wait for the request.

The problem it's that the back button added in the navigation bar seems to be blocked until de request finishes. The button remember the user interaction and when the request finishes go back automatically.

The request has a delegate method for the response and when the app enters on that method the button wake up and go back.

If I touch during a request the touch/click effect don't appear on the button, and it don't either at the end of the request. When I wait until the end, the button had the normal effect for a touched/clicked button.

Comment: You main thread is blocked by the request. Post some code, please.

Comment: @fsant if You found your answer from below post please inform us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can enable the button property like this.

```
 [button setEnable:Yes];
 [button setEnable:Yes];
```

also use this

```
 [button setuserintractionEnable:no];
```

Comment: I'm sure that's not the problem. Obviously the button *is* enabled (as you can tell from the question).

Comment: Then @Kai what he exactly want if your understand please edit the question.

Comment: I don't think, there is any need to edit something. It's perfectly described, that the button is blocked during the request, but after that it works ... So the button is obviously enabled.

Comment: Yes, I think so. That's why he wrote "The problem it's that the back button added in the navigation bar seems to be blocked until de request finishes." Moreover your answer, besides of don't answering the question, contains no single line of compiling code (even though you doubled one ;-) ).

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startRequest) withObject:nil];

Answer (score 0):

call your request in backgroundthread as

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startRequest) withObject:nil];
```

and remember this always for core data too. this is that your UI will be rleased and the request will continue to work in background thread
 and then implement request cancel on back button

initialize obj as

Obj *obj = [[Obj alloc] initWithDelegate:self selector:@selector(requestFinished)];
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startRequest:) withObject:obj];
obj has the attributes SEL selector, and id delegate;

when request finishes

check 
if ([obj.delegate respondsToSelector:obj.selctor])
{
 [obj.delegat performSelector:obj.selector];
}

inform me if you need more specs

Comment: The problem with this is that the delegate isn´t been awoke when the request is finished and i get the response

Comment: @fsantaolaya If you want to go anywhere with your question, please post some code

Comment: you can send an object having the selector and delegate and when request finish call back. see answer again after i edit it in a few minutes

Comment: check the anser now and tell me if it needs more explaination

Comment: @Kai the cuestion is that it's seems that the "block" is performed by the system when I try a request, but I'll try to put the code on an appropiate way.

Comment: @TheSaad I belive I understand this code, but sounds a bit strange `code` @interface Obj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL select;

@end                                                        @implementation Obj

@synthesize delegat;
@synthesize select;

@end`code` I'll check if this works fine